# Yocto - NodeJS minify assets

Tags: node.js, minify, yocto

I would like to minify the assets of a project running on node js. I don't want to minify directly on the target as the ARM processor we are using has not enough power to minify all the assets in a reasonable time at startup. Instead I would like to launch the minify process on the build host (Yocto). I have searched on the web for any help around this process but I did not.

Ideally I would like to use something like [node-minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-minify) that I could run in a js file from the build machine in the do_install task of Yocto.

I asked help first on ([meta-nodejs/issues/62](https://github.com/imyller/meta-nodejs/issues/62)) but I did not received assistance. Thus I'm now trying here as we are in a rush and I'm really out of idea on how to acheived this.

Here is a basic recipe and my questions :

```
SRC_URI = "svn://URL_TO_THE_TARGET_PROJECT \
    file://host-minify-asset-script.js"

DEPENDS = "nodejs-native "
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "nodejs "

inherit npm npm-install

do_install() {

    # This build/install dependency for target ?
    oe_runnpm install
    oe_runnpm prune --production

    # Is it the proper way to install node-minify on the host like this ?
    oe_runnpm_native install https://github.com/srod/node-minify/tarball/2.0.2

    # Now, how can I run natively my script (host-minify-asset-script.js) 
    # to minify the assets present in the work folder of the recipe ?
}
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) to minify your node source.

```
npm install -g uglify # install uglify

rm -rf ./minified # remove existing minified directory if it exists

# minify each .js file in the current directory and place the output in ./minified
find . -name "*.js" | xargs -I % sh -c 'mkdir -p ./minified/$(dirname %); uglify -s % -o ./minified/%'
```

Comment: Nice solution, thank you so much. Do I really need to install uglify globally "-g"  ? I'm curious, if I'm calling `node host-minify-asset-script.js` will it work and is the process will run on the build machine ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to install it globally. I don't see why you couldn't minify on the build machine and push the minified files to the production machine.

Comment: I incorrectly ask my question. Is calling `node host-minify-asset-script.js` in the do_install() task will be run on the build machine ? And, is the build machine will have the dependencies required to run node js even if node js is not installed on the build-machine ? According imyller on the github where I ask my initial question, the host machine is already configure to be able to run node via `nodejs-native`. Did I understand well ?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. I'm not familiar with your setup or yocto.

Comment: Is doing this in `do_install()` can works `oe_runnpm_native install uglify` follow by `find . -name "*.js" -exec uglifyjs -o {} {} \;`